# There is a linear map $\varphi:V\to V$ with $\ker \varphi= \operatorname{im} \varphi $ iff $n$ is even

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space.
>
> To prove:
>   $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}$
>   There is a linear map $\varphi:V\to V$ with $\ker \varphi= \im
>  \varphi $ if and only if  $n$ is even.

Solution:

"$\Rightarrow$" If $\ker \varphi=\im \varphi $ then $n = \dim \ker \varphi+ \dim \im \varphi = 2\cdot \dim \ker \varphi = 2\cdot \dim \im \varphi$

So $n$ is even.

How do I show the other direction "$\Leftarrow$"?

Can I say if $n$ is even, we know from "$\Rightarrow$" that there is a linear map?

Answer (score 7):

Select a basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{2N}$. Map $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ to 0, and $\{e_i\}_{i=N+1}^{2N}$ to $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ (by taking $e_i$ to $e_{-N+i} $). This is a map with the desired property.

Comment: That would be $\varphi = (0_n,\dotsc, 0_n, e_1, \dotsc e_N)$. The first half mapped to zero the second half to a set of $N$ linear independent vectors.

Comment: Yes, and the matrix in the answer below represents this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I say if $n$ is even, we know from "$\Rightarrow$" that there is a linear map?$\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}$

Note: You want to infer from the even dimension, and $V$ being a vector space, that there exists a linear map $\varphi$ from $V$ to $V$ with $\ker \phi = \im \phi$.